# Appending to a Response Body in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-management

I am working on a project where I am populating some pdfs on the back-end, then I convert those pdfs into a List of byte[] which gets merged into one very large array and finally, send back via the response body as a Memory Stream.
My issue is that this is a large amount of data and during the process of getting the list of byte arrays to merge I am using a lot of memory.
I am wondering if instead of converting the final merged byte[] into a Memory Stream and adding that to the response body; could I create several Memory Stream objects that I an append to the Response.Body as they are created? Alternatively, I wondered if there was a way to use the one Memory Stream and just keep adding to it as a create each new byte[] for each pdf document?

Edit: This is probably a little long winded but I was too vague with my original post. At the core of what I am trying to do I have several pdf documents, they are each several pages long. Each of them is represented in the code below as one of the byte[] items in the filesToMerge List. Ideally, I would like to go through these one by one and convert them into a memory stream and send them to the client one right after the other in a loop. However, when I try to do this I get errors that the Response body has already been sent. Is there a way to append something to the response body so it is updated each time through the loop?

```
    [HttpGet("template/{formId}/fillforms")]
    public void FillForms(string formId/*, [FromBody] IList<IDictionary<string, string>> fieldDictionaries*/)
    {
        List<byte[]> filesToMerge = new List<byte[]>();

        // For testing
        var mockData = new MockData();
        IList<IDictionary<string, string>> fieldDictionaries = mockData.GetMock1095Dictionaries();


        foreach(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary in fieldDictionaries)
        {
            var populatedForm = this.dataRepo.PopulateForm(formId, dictionary);
            // write to rb
            filesToMerge.Add(populatedForm);
        }

        byte[] mergedFilesAsByteArray = this.dataRepo.GetMergedByteArray(filesToMerge);

        this.SendResponse(formId + "_filled.pdf", new MemoryStream(mergedFilesAsByteArray));
    }

    private void SendResponse(string formName, MemoryStream ms, IDictionary<string, string> fieldData = null)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={formName}.pdf");
        ms.WriteTo(Response.Body);
    }
```

Comment: This question is a little open ended, although the story is a high level view of what you are doing, its hard to know what you are actually doing, and how we can reduce your allocations without seeing actual code

Comment: You can change your method FillForm to be a return type of IActionResult (public IActionResult FillForms) and then you will be able to use existing methods to expose file or content. See this link for an example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fileresult-in-asp-net-core-mvc2/

Answer (score 0):

Memory streams are really just byte arrays with a bunch of nice methods on top. So switching to byte arrays won't help that much. A problem that a log of people run into when dealing with byte arrays and memory streams is not releasing the memory when you are done with the data since they occupy the memory of the machine you are running on so you can easily run out of memory. So you should be disposing of data as soon as you don't need it anymore with "[using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)" as an example. Memory streams has a method called Dispose that will release all resources used by the stream

If you wanted to transfer the data from your application as quickly as possible the best approach would be to cut the stream into smaller parts and re-assemble them in the correct order at the destination. You could cut them to 1mb or 126kb really whatever you want. When you send the data to the destination you need to also pass what the order number of this part is because this method allows you to POSt the data in parallel and there is no guarantee of order.

To split a stream into multiple streams

```cs
private static List<MemoryStream> CreateChunks(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4000000]; //set the size of your buffer (chunk)
    var returnStreams = new List<MemoryStream>();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (true) //loop to the end of the file
        {
            var returnStream = new MemoryStream();
            int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //read each chunk
            returnStream.Write(buffer, 0, read); //write chunk to [wherever];
            if (read <= 0)
            { //check for end of file
                return returnStreams;
            }
            else
            {
                returnStream.Position = 0;
                returnStreams.Add(returnStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then looped through the streams that were created to create tasks to post to the service and each task would post to the server. I would await all of the tasks to finish then call my server again to tell it I had finished uploading and it could combine all of the data into one in the correct order. My service has the concept of an upload session to keep track of all of the parts and which order they would go in. It would also save each part to the database as they came in; in my case Azure Blob storage.

Comment: So my question is how do I cut the stream into smaller parts. When I try to send multiple streams I get errors that the response had already been started and I can't seem to find a way to append the data to the response in smaller chunks.

Comment: @reusablePants I have updated my answer to provide clarity and a code sample

Comment: this is probably my fault for not explaining the issue correctly. I am attempting to send back essentially, a bunch of pdfs. each byte[] represents one pdf. When I merge them into one byte[] I have not issues and receive the document on the client. However, the process of converting and storing each byte array until I can send them back is what is using up all the memory.

Comment: @reusablePants do you have to handle them all in one btye[]? There really isn't a way to decrease the memory load if all of the PDFs are in one byte[]. Do they need to be PDFs; you could try to convert them to a more efficient file type.

Comment: I do not have to handle them in one byte[]. In fact, I would ideally like to send back one byte[] at a time so I can dispose of the data after it has been sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you would be getting errors copying the contents of multiple `MemoryStream`s to the `Response.Body`. You should certainly be able to do this, although you'll need to be sure not to try and change response headers or the status code after you begin writing data (also don't try to call `Response.Clear()` after you begin writing data).

Here is a simple example of starting a response and then writing data:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RandomDataController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly ILogger<RandomDataController> logger;
    private const String CharacterData = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ";

    public RandomDataController(ILogger<RandomDataController> logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        this.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        this.Response.ContentLength = 1000;

        await this.Response.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        logger.LogInformation("Response Started");

        var rand = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            // You should be able to copy the contents of a MemoryStream or other buffer here instead of sending random data like this does.
            await this.Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CharacterData[rand.Next(0, CharacterData.Length)].ToString()), cancellationToken);
            Thread.Sleep(50); // This is just to demonstrate that data is being sent to the client as it is written
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (i % 100 == 0 && i > 0) {
                logger.LogInformation("Response In Flight {PercentComplete}", (Double)i / 1000);
            }
        }

        logger.LogInformation("Response Complete");
    }
}
```

You can verify that this streams data back to the client using netcat:

```
% nc -nc 127.0.0.1 5000
GET /randomdata HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: Close
```

(Enter an extra blank line after `Connection: Close` to begin the request). You should see data appear in netcat as it is written to `Response.Body` on the server.

One thing to note is that this approach involves calculating the length of the data to be sent up front. If you are unable to calculate the size of the response up front, or prefer not to, you can look into [Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), which ASP.Net should automatically use if you start writing data to the Response.Body without specifying the `Content-Length`.

Comment: I'm using netcat on a mac, so your command line may vary (some systems don't require `-c` for this to work).

Comment: I have attempted to implement your example but I am getting errors. I am doing this a little differently as I am trying to write each byte array, which represents a single pdf doc, into the response body. but when I use the same structure I get an error "Cannot write to the response body, the response has completed"

Comment: Can you share the code that is generating the errors?

Comment: `public async void FillFormsGetChunkedResponse(string formId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, [FromBody] IList<IDictionary<string, string>> fieldDictionaries)
{
    this.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    foreach (IDictionary<string, string> dictionary in fieldDictionaries)
    {
        var populatedForm = this.dataRepo.PopulateForm(formId, dictionary);
        await 
        this.Response.Body.WriteAsync((populatedForm),cancellationToken).AsTask();
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}`

Comment: Hmm, assuming that `this.dataRepo.PopulateForm` returns a `Byte[]` I cannot reproduce the issue you are having. Even without the ContentLength specified and without the Response.StartAsync, ASP.Net automatically streams back the result using chunked encoding. One thing I will mention is that your method declaration should be `public async Task` not `public async void`. It is a very bad idea to make a method `async void` because there is no way for the caller to wait for the asynchronous code to complete.

Comment: @reusablePants What ASP.Net version are you using? I've been testing with ASP.Net Core 3.1

Comment: Another note, I see you're using `[FromBody]` that should really only be used with `[HttpPost]` since the `GET` verb does not support sending a body.

Comment: BTW, if you need to share code in the comments it might be best to put your code into a gist: https://gist.github.com/ and link to it in the comment. It might actually be helpful to see more of your code because it's possible the issue is in something you're not showing (like your controller declaration). It would also be good to rule out the problem coming from some Middleware you have configured. For example here is 100% of the code I'm using to test this: https://gist.github.com/sflanker/cb32b57ecefe9a05b4dc715882395498